# How to delete a file from azure blob storage after downloading it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, .net-core, azure-blob-storage

I'm working on a blob storage system where my files are stored.
Right now, I'm able to delete/undelete files from my blob container.
I'm trying to download a file back from my controller to browser and delete the file.

Here's my download controller

```cs
    public ActionResult DownloadBlob(string name) {
            CloudBlobContainer container = GetCloudBlobContainer();
            var resultSegment = container.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(name.Split('/')[0],true ,BlobListingDetails.All,null,null,null,null).Result;
            CloudBlockBlob target = (CloudBlockBlob)resultSegment.Results.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Uri.Segments.Last() == name.Split('/')[1]);
            //var directory = container.GetDirectoryReference(name.Split('/')[0]);
            //var block = directory.GetBlockBlobReference(name.Split('/')[1]);

            if (target.ExistsAsync().Result) {
            } else {
                target.UndeleteAsync().Wait();
            }

            Stream stream = target.OpenReadAsync().Result;
            string contentType = target.Properties.ContentType;
            ;

            target.DeleteIfExistsAsync();

            return new FileStreamResult(stream, contentType) {
                FileDownloadName = "Downloaded_" + name.Split('/')[1]
            };
    }
```

So if I have a deleted file, I want to undelete it, download it then delete it again.(Soft Delete is turned on)
Is there a way to do this so deletion executes after return statement

Comment: You should change your controller action to be `async` so it doesn't deadlock when blocked on `.Result`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you facing the error "the blob is not found" in your current code? If yes,
you can use MemoryStream and blob.DownloadToStream(memoryStream), then you can just delete the blob after download completes, no need to call delete after return statement.

I installed this nuget package of blob storage: [Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob, Version 11.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob/), which supports async and non-async blob method. You can use this package or change your current code to async as per the comment.

Sample code works fine at my side(a test code, you can feel free to modify to meet your need):

```
    public IActionResult Contact()
    {
        string account_name = "xx";
        string account_key = "xx";

        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(account_name, account_key), true);
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("test1");
        CloudBlockBlob blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("df1.JPG");

        if (!blob.Exists())
        {
            blob.Undelete();
        }

        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        blob.DownloadToStream(memoryStream);
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        string contentType = blob.Properties.ContentType;

       blob.DeleteIfExists();

        return new FileStreamResult(memoryStream, contentType)
        {
            FileDownloadName = blob.Name
        };

    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly for what I needed.
Also, I learned something new today. I didn't know that you had to reset the MemoryStream Position back to 0.
2-for-1 :)